# what if after-directory not in HOME

Tags: vim, directory, structure

I would like to put my gvim 'after' directory in my favorite place other than $HOME/vimfiles/after. But adding to rtp only cause these after scripts be loaded right *BEFORE* the ft-plugin scripts are loaded.
So what is the simple solution?

BR, Ruochen

Comment: What do you mean adding to `rtp` only causes these scripts to be loaded before the ftplugin scripts? (How did you add the directory to `rtp`?)

Comment: I mean set rtp+=ATER_DIR. If I set rtp+=UPPER_DIR_OF_AFTER, the after scripts will not be loaded at all.

Comment: As long as you _append_, the load order (from left to right) should be fine. Please show us a sketch of the directories, and `:scriptnames` output if you have a problem there.

Answer (score 0):

The user's *after* directory is just another root entry to be searched in `'runtimepath'`. Looking at the default:

```
    PC, OS/2: "$HOME/vimfiles,
            $VIM/vimfiles,
            $VIMRUNTIME,
            $VIM/vimfiles/after,
            $HOME/vimfiles/after"
```

It is safe to replace the final `$HOME/vimfiles/after` (or just add) with another one, e.g. `$HOME/elsewhere/after`. (Though I don't understand the motivation for that; all under `$HOME/vimfiles` is under your user's control; why put the (sparsely populated) after structure somewhere else, as this doesn't affect the crucial load order.)

Comment: There are several reasons: 1. I use gvim gui as well as vim on cygwin term so that I wish they share only one suite of scripts. 2. I would like use git to make version controls on these scripts since I don't want to backup everywhere. If I put them on the default $HOME directory and one day I have to reinstall win7 I usually format the system disk as well. If it happen that I forget copy the scripts out, it will really be a big disaster.

Comment: I beg your pardon, but none of these reasons make sense to me, especially since you've only asked about the _after_ directory, not the entire Vim user configuration.

Comment: sorry i misunderstood the use of after-directory. I thought they were loaded after all the other scripts had been loaded so that I could override some file-type relative settings. Now I used other ways to achieve it.

Comment: Yes, scripts in the after directory run at the end, and it is typically used to override filetype-specific things. But for that, you can keep them right along your other config, under `$HOME/vimfiles/after`. The strange thing is that you want to move just the after directory, but not your normal user configuration at `$HOME/vimfiles`.

Comment: Oh, I did not mention it clearly. Actually I put my entire vimfiles directory in a place rather than $HOME. It seemed that the `after' mechanism did not take affects if vimfiles was not placed in $HOME.

Comment: Well, this just confirms the "garbage in, garbage out" rule :-( Hope you learn from this and put in a precise description of what you got (how you changed `'rtp'` in this case) next time!